# Opening a file with an application running in background

Tags: ios, swift, file

I am creating an app that should be able to open an external file when I tap my app icon in **"Open in"** dialog box for that file. In order to do that I assume I could get the file data through `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) or application(_:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` in `AppDelegate`, from where I can get the url for the external file. when the app is launched.

However, my app is expected to be already running in background when I tap its icon in **"Open in"** dialog box for the file. So, `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) or application(_:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` never get called, since the app will return from background in this case, and so, only function `applicationWillEnterForeground(_:)` in `AppDelegate` gets called.

Any ideas how can I solve this problem? (Sorry for my bad English)

Comment: Have you looked into `application(_:open:options:)`? (I'm actually not sure if that's the method that gets called in this case, but I think it's at least something similar?) See: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623112-application

Comment: @TylerTheCompiler, I'll try that and I'll post here the result. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @TylerTheCompiler, your suggestion worked wonderfully. I don't know how I can thank you as much as I would like to.

Comment: Oh okay great! I'll add it as an answer and you can upvote and select it as the answer if you want. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into `application(_:open:options:)`. This gets called when your app is already running instead of `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` when another app wants to open your app.

See Apple's documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623112-application